# How to speed up tkinter Label image update

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on a simple python/tkinter tool to display some sensor data and a history graph for some of the values which is running on a raspberry pi 4.

The widget does actually work but every update of the history graph (< 10 kB .png image) takes about 1 second. As long as it is display-only, it doesn't really matter, but I want to change the labels containing the sensor data to buttons which activate the corresponding history graph (currently it is a time triggered rotation). During the the update of the image the whole gui is frozen, which I would like to avoid.

This is the code I'm using:

```
import tkinter as tk
import time
import multiprocessing as mp

root = tk.Tk()
bottomFrame = tk.Frame(root, width=1024, height=130)
bottomFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=1, pady=1)

mgr = mp.Manager()
image_global = mgr.list(['/path/to/images_1', '/path/to/images_2'])

#labels = {f'label_{row}_{col}' : [create_label(bottomFrame, row, col), row, col] for row in range(3) for col in range(6)}

#for label in labels.values():
#  label[0].grid(row=label[1], column=label[2], padx=3 if args.graph else 20, pady=1, ipadx=2, ipady=2)

#def update_values():
#  for label in labels.values():
#    label[0].config(text=create_label_text(label[1], label[2], data_global))
#  root.after(update_interval, update_values)

#root.after(update_interval, update_values)

##### ##### ##### ##### ##### #####
##### Beginning of graph part #####

graph = tk.Label(bottomFrame)
graph.image = tk.PhotoImage(file=image_global[1])
graph.config(image = graph.image)
graph.grid(row=0, column=6, rowspan=3)

def update_images():
    start = time.time() ## Debug
    graph.image = tk.PhotoImage(file=image_global[1])
    mid = time.time() ## Debug
    graph.config(image = graph.image)
    end = time.time() ## Debug
    print(f'load image: {mid - start}, configure graph: {end - mid}') ## Debug
    root.after(5000, update_images)

root.after(5000, update_images)

root.mainloop()
```

image_global[1] contains the image path (/tmp/sensors/graphs/XYZ.png) and is updated in a separate process. The sensor values are also updated in a separate process and the reconfiguration of the labels doesn't cause any noticible lag.

The output usually looks like this:

```
load image: 0.002164602279663086, configure graph: 1.0156207084655762
load image: 0.008348226547241211, configure graph: 0.9867994785308838
load image: 0.006554126739501953, configure graph: 0.9840545654296875
```

I don't really understand why it takes so long to change such a small image. Is there any way to speed things up? I already tried to use Canvas instead of Label, but that doesn't have any effect on the speed.

Edit: commented out non-relevant code, added definitions

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can help. There are several undefined functions and variables in your code.

Comment: try using `<tk.Canvas>.create_image`, in my experience using `.config` is kinda the slowest approach, another one that was faster was pre-preparing images and putting them on labels, then just using any layout manager appeared to be faster than `.config`